# Where is my PHPstorm plugin going wrong

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to create a basic plugin which basically adds live-templates / snippets to PHPStorm.

When I install it by entering PHPStorm > Settings > Plugins and clicking on "Install plugin from disk". After selecting the jar file I created, it appeared in the plugins list with the correct title, description, change log etc, then it asks me to restart and all appears to have worked well.

The only issue is the live templates are not working at all. What am I doing wrong?

https://github.com/JasonMortonNZ/test-phpstorm-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this in plugin.xml

`<depends>com.intellij.modules.lang</depends>`

Comment: Add that but still joy